# Textbox doesn't get any values

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to program an Age Calculator in seconds, but the TextBox txtOutput doesn't get any values. There are no compile Errors, so it has to be another error, but I can't detect it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public DateTime bDate;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnBerechne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        DateTime birthDate = dtpInput.Value;
        txtOutput.Text = GetAge(bDate);        
    }

    public string GetAge(DateTime bDate)
    {
        DateTime birthDate = dtpInput.Value;
        TimeSpan Calculator = DateTime.Now - birthDate;
        int x = (int) Calculator.TotalSeconds;
        return x.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciatied. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging you code?

Comment: have you tried txtOutput.Refresh() ?

Answer (score 0):

It works with this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public DateTime bDate;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSeconds.Text = GetAge(Convert.ToDateTime(dtpInput.Text));
    }

    public string GetAge(DateTime bDate)
    {
        DateTime birthDate = bDate;
        TimeSpan Calculator = DateTime.Now - birthDate;
        int x = (int)Calculator.TotalSeconds;
        return x.ToString();
    }
}
```

[image: Running example]